# Laravel 5 api route

Tags: php, laravel

**Brief:**

Actually, I'm little bit confused while using Laravel api route file.

**Question:**

If I need to access the data of my web site in other platform (**like android app**) that is made using laravel, then should I create a different route in `api.php` file?

If yes then I will be declaring two routes and controllers for each request, first in `web.php` and second in `api.php`. Is it correct?

Basically, I want to ask that how I can make an api, so that I can access the data in website as well as in other platforms?

I was searching for a good tutorial for this, but I didn't got a good one.

Comment: Ideally your API routes would be returning data in a format consumable by API's, like JSON. Your web routes should be returning actual web pages.

Comment: So, should I have different route and controllers for api and website?

Comment: The way a lot of people do it is first write your API with API controllers, then you write your web controllers to consume the data from the API. This is assuming that your front end is going to be set up to consume those API's (via Vue or some other JS framework). If you didn't plan to have the frontend based off of your API, then you would write your web controllers completely separate from the API.

Comment: And what about post request. Should I send request to api routes. And one more thing, If I will be using api route, there will be no csrf protection. Does it matter??

Comment: You can still have CSRF protection, see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token).

Comment: No, I created a post route in api.php. Then I send data to this request using POSTMAN. There was no csrf protection.

Comment: Oh, you're actually right, CSRF is [only in the web routes by default (see paragraph under the code)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-introduction), but you can include the CSRF middleware in the API routes if you wanted to. Though, the recommended way is to use some kind of JWT (probably via Pasport) for auth to prevent any kind of misuse.

Comment: Can you suggest me a good tutorial series for creating an api using Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the API routes and Web routes should be completely different but if you want it to be same then instead of defining routes in different file you can add routes only in **web.php** and add a special parameter from your client and in controller if you are getting the parameter then return the JSON Object or else return the view.

Eg.

web.php

```
Route::get('getUsers','UserController@getUsers');
```

UserController.php

```
...
public function getUsers(Request $request)
{
    ...

    if ($request->has('api')) {
        return $users; //API Route (Laravel will by Default return the JSON Response no need to do json_encode)
    }

    return view('pages.user_list'); //Normal Routes hence returning View
}
...
```

Requests
Normal Request

```
<Yourdomain>/getUsers
```

API Request

```
<Yourdomain>/getUsers?api=true
```

I hope that helped...

Comment: 2 options 1) Disable the CSRF Validation for those routes(Not Recommended), 2) You can make an API where you can return the CSRF token and in next request you can simply pass it from your client. and for token authentication you can use JWT Auth https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Answer (score 1):

Write your api routes in `api.php` and web routes in `web.php`.

The Api routes always have the name `api` in the routes thus you can differentiate the routes., I mentioned here because as @Akshay Khale mentioned an example with query parameter.

if you want to use the same controller for both API and Web, Api Requests always have the Header `Content-Type : Json` and `"Accept":"application/json"` so in your controller you can do it as below.

```
public function getUsers(Request $request)
{
    ...

    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        return response()->json($users, 200); //here why we are extending response object because using json() method you can send the status code with the response. 

    }

    return view('pages.user_list'); //Normal Routes hence returning View
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for the laravel 5.6 and above the above answers won't work for me , so here is my 2 cents.

I have put the routes in `web.php` and `api.php` and normal  no any magic tricks .

```
public function getUsers(Request $request)
{
    ....

    if( $request->is('api/*')){
        ...
        return response()->json($user_data, 200);
    }
    ...
    return view('users', ['users_data'=>$user_data]);
}
```

It will return json output for

> 127.0.0.1:8000/api/users

and normal view in html for

> 127.0.0.1:8000/users